# Turtlebot+Object detector

Tags: ros, turtlebot, roboearth, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to add a object detector to the turtlebot. I was thinking of the roboearth software (http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth). The bad thing is that turtlebot is written for ros-diamondback and roboearth software for ros-electric.
My question is: Is it easy to change the software so it support other ros release? If it's possible which way is easier, change the turtlebot to electric or change the roboearth to the diamondback?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11720/turtlebot+object-detector/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question (upgrading TurtleBot): http://answers.ros.org/question/2519/upgrading-turtlebot-to-electric , has an answer for how to upgrade TurtleBot to electric (there is a tutorial)

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even if the RoboEarth software would compile and run under ROS Diamondback, it is
not recommended to do so.
Some ROS packages we use changed significantly from Diamondback to Electric (e.g. the
PCL library), so we cannot guarantee the software will work as expected under Diamondback.

There are instructions available to upgrade your TurtleBot drivers from Diamondback to Electric, though. See e.g. [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/electric/Robot%20Upgrade).

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1